# Magento 2.1.X Admin Shipping Method Loop Through Cart Items

Tags: admin, magento-2.1, shipping-methods

I am trying to make my shipping plugin work in the admin.

My plugin requires me to loop through the cart
How do I Make this work with the admin?

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepo,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
)
{
parent::__construct($context);
$this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
$this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
$this->_productRepo = $productRepo;
$this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
$this->_cart = $cart;
}


public function getCartItems()
    {
    foreach($this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
        {
        $sku = $item->getSku();
        }

    }
```

This errors out when trying to pull the cart.  No error just skips over it.
I think I need to access the session and the cart a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is related to the fact that you're requesting a new instance of the cart model in your constructor. This will be an empty model and won't have any data, leading to the issue you described.

While you could figure out a way to get the current cart, I suggest pulling the quote from the checkout session with `Magento\Checkout\Model\Session->getQuote()` and then using the items from there. In your case, replace the line `$this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems()` with `$this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems()`.

Please let me know if you have any questions. If the answer is helpful to you, please hit the checkmark next to it to accept it as the solution.

Comment: hi tjons, thanks for the fast reply... sorry for my slow delay.   going from _cart to _checkoutSession  did not work.

Comment: $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getPostCode() is not even available.   I am in the ADMIN.